# Remove relative path in header file when include header file via cmake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I put a certain `header.h` file in `project/include/subfolder1`

And enter the following in `other.h` in `project/include/subfolder2`

```
#include "header.h"
```

and i got this in `other.h`:

```
/subfolder1/other.h:8:10: fatal error: other2.h: No such file or directory
    8 | #include "other2.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Can I use cmake to solve it without using relative paths or absolute path?
i used `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${subDir})` but it not work.

I need some hints, any help is greatly.

Below is my cmakelist.txt in project:

```
macro(addAllSubDirectory subDir)
    message("include ./${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${subDir}")
    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${subDir})
    FILE(GLOB children RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${subDir} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${subDir}/*)
    foreach(child ${children})
        if(IS_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${subDir}/${child})
            addAllSubDirectory(${subDir}/${child})
        endif()
    endforeach()
endmacro()

#===============================
# Init Project
#===============================
project(testProject)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})

#===============================
# include
#===============================
addAllSubDirectory(subfolder1)
```

Comment: You need to specify the directories with `target_include_directories(...)`

Comment: And if you invoke your compiler directly, this is the role of the `-I` flag.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX no, i used `target_include_directories` but it not work, I didn't mention this point, I have now updated the question.

Comment: _ @YSC has cmakely solution?

Comment: Yes, see first comment. If it doesn't work you used it wrong. Show us your code.

Comment: You realize that you called the macro for subfolder1 but not for subfolder2??

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Jesus, I actually made exactly the same mistakes in sample and production, and now they are both work!!